# How to achieve 4k 60 Hz output through USB C from notebook?

Tags: graphics-card, external-display, intel-graphics, usb-c, 4k-resolution

I am using a Dell Precision 5550 (I assume similar to [this configuration](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/precision-5550-workstation/spd/precision-15-5550-laptop/s005p555015us_vivp)) and have a USB-C Dock ([link to German product page on Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08Q845V9B)) connected to it that claims to be able to output 4k 60 Hz content via HDMI. The monitor connected to the HDMI port of that dock is also capable of 4k 60 Hz and I use the included HDMI cable of that monitor, so that should also be capable of handling that.

Unfortunately I only get 30 Hz at 4k resolution, which is sadly quite noticeable.

Is there a way to get 60 Hz output with this combination? Or is the Intel UHD graphics solution of that processor (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201897/intel-core-i7-10850h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-5-10-ghz.html) just not capable of that?
Also, there is an Nvidia Quadro T2000 built in, but afaik it is not possible to use that instead for video output to external monitors?

Comment: Well you need an active DisplayPort – HDMI, adapter, that’s for sure. Unfortunately, Dell documentation is rather incomplete regarding display output specs, but I guess you have DisplayPort 1.4.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to find out what version of DisplayPort the USB-C (and Thunderbolt 3) ports do support. If it really is DP 1.4 then at least the Dock should easily support 60 Hz at its HDMI port. The question is whether there is a limitation from the integrated graphics.

Comment: The USB-C Dock explicitly talks about DisplayPort versions. So just for my understanding: Does it use DisplayPort for data transmission and then converts it internally to HDMI, which can be connected to from its ports?

Comment: I have just added a link to the product page of the USB-C Dock on Amazon (German)

Comment: I have circumvented the problem by buying an extra USB-C to DP cable. Possibly also a dock offering DP instead of HDMI connectors might have worked. Did not know that was important when purchasing the dock.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As written already, the problem seems to be the limitations of HDMI for this setup.

I have circumvented the problem by buying an extra USB-C to DP cable. Possibly also a dock offering DP instead of HDMI connectors might have worked. Did not know that was important when purchasing the dock.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a limitation of the [Intel Core i7 10850H](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201897/intel-core-i7-10850h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-5-10-ghz.html) embedded graphics, Intel UHD Graphics.

The product's page linked above informs:

> Max Resolution (HDMI):
> 4096 x 2304@30Hz

60Hz only via DisplayPort.

Comment: I also read that, but am rather skeptical whether it is relevant, since I use a USB-C Dock (which might actually rely on DisplayPort for data transmission).

Comment: It is relevant because it is the same signal, the "carrier" is irrelevant. Unlike what you're thinking no, it isn't a DisplayPort-converted-to-HDMI.

Comment: So it is an HDMI signal carried over DP (or USB-C)?

Answer (score 0):

On the HP laptops using usbc display alt mode they are configured to only output max 4k30 by default.  You can however in the bios use a hi resolution mode, this will allow 4k60 using uhd graphics. This will however limit the usb speeds on the docking station to usb2 speeds.

There may be similar settings in your bios.

hope this helps anyone in the future.!